# Position Absolute and Bottom 0

Tags: css

http://cdpn.io/FykHr
I seem to have an issue with the combined CSS properties:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

First you can see that the .footer div doesn't isn't at the bottom. Now, change the `font-size` from `120px` to `50px` and the div seems to be working the way I inteded it to.

How do I make the .footer div stay at the bottom (not fixed at the bottom of the screen) regardless of the size of the .content div.

Comment: On my Firefox, codepen website (not your code) doesn't work. On Chromium your code works and I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to the parent container, which in this case is `.wrapper`.

Here's a good reference [page on absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Comment: Worked for me. Was having trouble getting a modal window to stretch to the bottom of the page. Set `position: relative` on the `<body>` tag and magic.

Comment: 10-years later and still saving the day @keirog! Worked for me. I develop in Ruby on Rails and something in one of my gems (either Bootstrap or the like) changed and all of a sudden a rounded buttom of my nav section was being sent to the bottom of the webpage. When I apply this answer to the parent container "navbar", everything works as expected.

Answer (score 12):

There is one way to do that:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8UNM/

There is still one limitation. You have to know height of footer and set it in two places.

Comment: Works as required :) I hope it has no effect on any other child elements.