# Div having Overlay css class is getting created at the sameplace

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, less

I want to create an overlay div inside another div[The overlay div is generated dynamically inside a for loop]. But when I write position:absolute inside my overlay class, the inner div is getting created at same position.

[image]

My requirement is to show multiple "TOTAL USERS (NUMBER)" in the middle of the chart.
So I have written an overlay css class. Inside the overlay class I have given `position:absolute` . As a result all the divs are getting created at same place over each other.

[image]

See at the above image the "TOTAL USER" part is overwritten at same place.

overlay class is:

```
   .overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:22px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML vide code:

```
<div *ngFor="let chart of chartData[0].values" class="child">
            <div class="chart-goal-name">{{goalName}}</div>
            <div class="overlay">TOTAL USERS {{userCount}} </div>
            <div class="chart-holder">
              <nvd3 [options]="donutChartOptions"
                [data]="chart"
                class="top-1">
              </nvd3>
            </div>
            
          </div>
```

Comment: @ChrisG Didn't get you. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: position absolute required position relative to parent -- add css to parent .child{position:relative;}.

Comment: Perfect... This works. Thanks @SumitPatel

Comment: great i add this as answer.

Comment: This is CSS 101: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_Block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Position Absolute and Bottom 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612951/position-absolute-and-bottom-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you use `position:absolute;` parent required `position` `relative`.

add below css.

```
.child{position:relative;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using the absolute position. So when you write left property or top property it is calculated from the screen left and screen top. So all the div created dynamically would be rendered in the same position.

So basically you need to give different left value for each. For this you can add the value of the left position in the object that is used for interation.

You can also add the top position in the object used for generating the **chartData[0].values**

and then use the value of top and left from the object and set it in the html as shown below.

```
 <div *ngFor="let chart of chartData[0].values" class="child">
            <div class="chart-goal-name">{{goalName}}</div>
            <div class="overlay"  [ngStyle]="{'left':chart.left, 'top': chart.top}">TOTAL USERS {{userCount}} </div>
            <div class="chart-holder">
              <nvd3 [options]="donutChartOptions"
                [data]="chart"
                class="top-1">
              </nvd3>
            </div>
            
          </div>
```

Comment: How can I fix this. I want to show "TOTAL USERS count" inside each donut chart dynamically.

Comment: I have edited the answer by writing the code sample that you can use to resolve the issue.

Comment: Both the answers are correct. Both are working for me. Thanks @minalshah